# Python selenium code seems to wait after calling javascript that display modal dialog box

Tags: python, selenium, automation, modal-dialog, popup

I'm using Python and Selenium to write an automation script in Internet Explorer.

When the web page throws up some kind of modal dialog box, the Python code stops running and just waits for some action to be taken on the popup.  After you press the "yes" or "no" button, then the Python code continues.

I believe the underlying Javascript function that is getting called (saveClicked()) is generating the popup box using this line of code:
var result=window.showModalDialog('whatever....')

Does anyone know how to handle this in Selenium? I want my code to click "ok" in this window or to just accept it. I tried right-clicking on the window to look at source code, etc. but those options are not given to me...the only options are "move/close".

I've looked to see if there is some kind of default IE capability in Selenium that will just automatically accept all modal dialog boxes but haven't found any. I also thought of maybe wrapping the call to the Javascript function with something that would somehow send a keystroke to the alert.  I'm open to anything!

Here is the code:  It never moves past the .execute_script line...it just sits there waiting.

```
print('Saving')

# I have to do this because I can't get the handle to the save button
# using any of the known Selenium methods but calling the JS works
driver.execute_script('saveClicked();')

print('Test')
driver.switch_to().alert().send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

The code just STOPS after the Javascript is executed and never moves to the print('test') line or any other code I put there.

Any python selenium code suggestions to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share a Minimal Reproducible Example!

Answer (score 0):

one way: you can try to use `Alert` to manage popups

```
Alert(driver).accept()
```

otherwise you can see the active window or tab with:

```
#get current window handle
p = driver.current_window_handle

#get windows
chwd = driver.window_handles

driver.switch_to.window(chwd[1])
```

reference:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.alert

Comment: Hi Jain - I tried that and the code never moves to the next line.  my code looks like this:

print('Saving...')
driver.execute_script('saveClicked();')
print('Test')
driver.switch_to.alert()

The code just stops at the execute Javascript function and never moves to the next line.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: This is far not the best solution.

Comment: Any of the alert methods won't work because it's not an alert.  It's a modal popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
message = "saveClicked()"  # or any other of your messages 
driver.execute_script(f"alert(\"{message}\");")
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Comment: So the 'saveClicked()" is a Javascript function that has a lot of code in it, and when executed, eventually throws up this modal alert/window.  Would this code still work ok?

Comment: In my example, saveClicked() is not a function, but just a string. Your mistake, as I see it, is using driver.switch_to().alert().accept() instead of driver.switch_to.alert.accept().

Comment: Hi Vitaliis - so the only problem is that once the execute_script line runs, the program never advances to the next line (which in this case would be driver.switch_to.alert.accept().  It just sits there waiting for a button on the modal window to be pressed.  Any other thoughts to solve it?

Comment: If it is a standard alert, my code has to close the window. Probably, your alert is not a standard browser alert, but a custom modal dialog.

Comment: Yes, it is not an alert.  It is a modal dialog.  Is there any way to close it or accept it?

Comment: Then you cannot use a standard method for closing alerts, it just will not ever work. You need to specify the exact locator for an OK/Accept button